# Strange behavior with image inside floated container

Tags: html, css

Given this simple layout:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="imgContainer">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/400x400">
  </div>
  <div>
    This should always stay to the right of the image.
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
  height: 20vh;
}

.imgContainer {
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
}

img {
  height: 100%;
}
```

---

**Issue #1**

Chrome, Firefox, and Opera correctly display it like this:

[image]

IE11 incorrectly puts the text 400 pixels to the right, based on the natural width of the image:

[image]

---

**Issue #2**

As you increase the window's height, the text should stay glued to the right of the image.  This works correctly in Firefox.

However, the text overlaps the image in Chrome and Opera:

[image]

---

See the behavior in this **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4cepx1f5/1/)**.

**Question:**  Is there a style I can add that will cause all browsers to behave consistently?

*[Note: I discovered this while working on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34112028/resizing-image-to-fit-td-or-div/).  I thought I had a solution, until I realized it wasn't responsive in any browser except Firefox.]*

Comment: Is it an option to use `background-image` instead of actual image?

Comment: @Cheslab, since this isn't my code, I'm not sure if that's an option.  But does that solve the problem?

Comment: If you don't have an image then IE won't know it's original width and it should put the text right after the image. This have one disadvantage - you have to set width to the `.imgContainer ` which I believe will solve the problem by itself. I just tried to add `width: 20vh;` to this div and IE now display everything correctly

Comment: Thanks, @Cheslab, explicitly setting a width probably solves it for all browsers.  But then it's no longer responsive.

Comment: It is, because you're using `vh`. Other way it's not clear for me what you want

Comment: Sorry, I meant it's not responsive based on height.  See the linked post to understand what the OP is trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following might do the trick.

Instead of using `float`, I would suggest using CSS tables.

Apply `display: table` to `.container` and set the height as needed.

For the two child elements, `.imgContainer` and `.panel`, use `display: table-cell` and inherit the height from the parent block.

I think this is pretty close to what you need, should work in all browsers
(but I did not check...)

```css
.container {
  height: 20vh;
  display: table;
}
.imgContainer, .panel {
  display: table-cell;
  height: inherit;
  vertical-align: top;
}
img {
  vertical-align:top;
  height: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="imgContainer">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/400x400">
  </div>
  <div class="panel">
    This should always stay to the right of the image.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @RickHitchcock Please check update, pretty close I think.

Comment: That fixes it in all browsers!  I would have thought `height: 100%` would do the same thing as `height: inherit`, but not in this situation.  Interesting!